# Reversing a String with Recursion

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am getting into recursion and I wanted to do a simple thing as reversing a string. The function is working but I don't understand how and that makes me very frustrated.(the recursive part)

```
function reverseString(myString) {
if (myString == "") {
    return "";
}
else {
    return reverseString(myString.substr(1)) + myString.charAt(0);
}}
```

Let's say I have a string "**abcd**". So the first loop would be:

"**myString.substr(1)**" makes from "**abcd**" -> "**bcd**" and then "**charAt(0)**" gets "**b**";

The result would be "**bcd + b**"? Or does "**myString.charAt(0)**" get executed when the recursion is finished?

**I am completely lost ... how does the whole procedure look like?**

Comment: `substr` doesn't change the value of `myString`. `myString.charAt(0)` would be `"a"` on the first call.

Comment: if "a" is on the first call then wouldn't the result be: abcd?

Comment: No, because it's getting concatenated to the end of the string.

Comment: While it's cool to do recursion, don't use this for large strings unless you like stack overflows.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

No, all of the parameters that you are passing in to the recursive call are evaluated before the recursive call. (Clarification: this means only `myString.substr(1)` )

You are correct, `myString.charAt(0)` gets executed after your recursive call returns. This makes it more complex than so-called "tail recursion" or "head recursion" in which the recursive call is the last or first operation (respectively) in your recursive function. Writing a tail recursive or head recursive function can help certain compilers produce more efficient code and it also helps make your function more understandable, but it isn't "required".

Here's how it looks:

```
abcd
bcd + a
cd + ba
d + cba
dcba
```

Comment: The readability is a matter of opinion. In a functional programming language (where recursion is used heavily), this would make perfect sense.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have a compiler.

Comment: I did not dislike, because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: I still don't understand which part attaches the "b" before "a"

Comment: Because I get it now. I console.log the return and I saw what it does.

Comment: Whether `myString.charAt(0)` is executed before or after the recursive call isn't relevant. `myString` *is not mutated*.

Comment: It doesn't look like that at all. Only 1 char is being appended to the result of reverseString so you don't get more than 1 on the RHS

Comment: Also, the talk about "head recursion" potentially allowing for more efficient code seems like nonsense.  There's "tail recursion" and non-tail recursion.

Comment: Finally, I'm sorry, but your "Here's how it looks" example is not correct either.  I'm guessing that you meant  `reverseString("abcd")` => `reverseString("bcd") + "a"` => `reverseString("cd") + "ba"` => ..., but even that's wrong.  "b" and "a" would not be concatenated solely to each other at any step, and concatenation would not happen until the stack unwinds from the recursion.

Answer (score 3):

> "myString.substr(1)" makes from "abcd" -> "bcd" and then "charAt(0)"
>   gets "b";

No, `myString.substr(1)` returns a new string with value `"bcd"`, the value of `myString` doesn't change, so when `myString.charAt(0)` is called the value `"a"` is returned because it is indexing the original string with the value `"abcd"`

Comment: Yes, thank you. I got it now after some tests with console.log.

Answer (score 1):

Look at how this evaluates

return reverseString(myString.substr(1)) + myString.charAt(0); 
Step 1 : return **reverseString("bcd")** + a; 
Step 2 : return **reverseString("cd")** + b + a; 
Step 3 : return **reverseString("d")** + c + b + a ; 
Step 4 : return **reverseString("")** + d + c + b + a;

Comment: Yes, thank you, I do get it now. It just clicked in my head couple of minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

Mystring is not modified when you call the substr method.

```
var mystring = 'abcd';
mystring.substr(1);

console.log(mystring) // abcd
```

This means that each recursive call is call a brand new string with the first character moved to the end of the string.

First call : recursiveString(bcd) + a

Second call: recursiveString(cd) + b

Third call: recursiveString(d) + c

Last call : recursiveString("") + d

Remember each recursive call is returning ONE character and then a function to retrieve more of them. The one character returned on each call occurs after the function.

So the function builds the string like : "" -> d -> c -> b -> a

Comment: Yes, thank you, I do get it now. It just clicked in my head couple of minutes ago.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's more helpful to look at it in the order in which things are **returned** from the (nested) calls to reverseString, since it keeps calling into reverseString until it passes in an empty string - that's the point it starts returning things.

```
call reverseString("abcd")
  call reverseString("bcd")
    call reverseString("cd")
      call reverseString("d")
        call reverseString("")
          return ""
        add "d" then return
      add "c" then return 
    add "b" then return
  add "a" then return
```

Comment: Thank you, I already got it. I also watched a video by computerphile which helped to understand the stack. (or the code you wrote)

Comment: I love recursion too, so it took me a little while to figure it out.  But it is also great for stack overflows :)

Comment: p.s. if you worked for me and did this you'd be in trouble, this is a fairly awful use of heap (at best 1 alloc and free per char) and stack (prob blow up if you gave it a 64k string). Reversing a string should be done in place, but I understand the appeal of recursion from an intellectual exercise POV